# How to open JasperReports's report on Client Side

Tags: java, web, jasper-reports, client-side

Im working in a Web application that allow the user to create and see the information from database with a *JasperReports*'s report. The JasperReports works and I can see the copy in the server side.

The problem appears when I want to show the results to client in his computer. 
The application send me a `java.awt.HeadlessException` because of AWT library that JasperReports use.

```
public void createView(){
        jasperViewer = new JasperViewer (reportFilled);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Its a very easy code, but I don't know how to fix this problem or its possible to use other libraries.

Some one can help me with other idea or know how to solve this?

Comment: This exception occurs only when you run a code in a non-awt environment  such as servers. are you sure that you run the code at client side.

Comment: It is used in a server. The code its written in a JSF bean and the method is called when client click in a button. The report is created and seved as a file, but when i want to use the JasperViewr crash. ¿there are other way to let the client show the report?

Comment: Jasperviewer is a swing based viewer component. in a jsf application you must convert jasperreport to html to view in a web page.

Comment: hope answer below helpfull.

Comment: Its very difficult to find some answrs at this page becouse people make different questions. The option that you bring me, its near the solution then I can say that help me. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs only when you run a code in a non-awt environment such as servers. Take a look at link below about the solution.

[How do I prevent a headless exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403190/how-do-i-prevent-a-headless-exception-in-java)

If you want to run report in a server environment then show user in a web page  you must convert to jasper print to html. take a look this answer for how to do that.

[View report using JasperViewer or something else in web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957825/view-report-using-jasperviewer-or-something-else-in-web-application)

Comment: It is better to mark question as duplicate and not to clone answers