# How can I run Java without GUI (where isHeadless is true)?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I guess many people think this question has duplicated ones.
However, this question precisely asks

how can I run Java where `!GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` returns `true`

The answer would be like

```
java --gui=disabled -jar hoge.jar
```

Comment: Do you mean `-Djava.awt.headless=true`?

Comment: ah, thank you very much!

Comment: For [Setting headless mode programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552371/setting-java-awt-headless-true-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commandline parameter `-Djava.awt.headless=true` can be used to set the headless mode from the commandline.

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552371/setting-java-awt-headless-true-programmatically) shows ways to set it programmatically, which is somewhat trickier but may be preferrable if you don't want or can't access the commandline parameters.

Comment: it helped a lot!